# OAUTH 2.0 - Access policy - acces denied CodeIgniter API

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, oauth

My request in postman works perfect, if callback url is incorrect i get an error specific, but on this cause, only i've got is a hangup

F5 NETWORK

Your session could not be established.

The session reference number:  e2c6b34d

Access was denied by the access policy. This may be due to a failure to meet access policy requirements.
If you are an administrator, please go to Access Policy >> Reports : All Sessions page and look up the session reference number displayed above.

There is my controller:

`<?php

class Etransport extends MY_Controller {

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('httpclient');
}

public function index() {
    
    $this->data['page_title'] = $this->lang->line('add_etransport');
        
    $this->page_construct('settings/etransport', $this->data);
    
}

public function getAnafToken() {
    $clientId = 'xxx';
    $clientSecret = 'fxxx';
    
    $oauthUrl = 'https://logincert.anaf.ro/anaf-oauthv2/v1/authorize';
    
    $redirectUrl = base_url('etransport/callback');
    $redirectUrl .= '?clientId=' . urlencode($clientId);
    $redirectUrl .= '&clientSecret=' . urlencode($clientSecret);

    redirect("$oauthUrl?client_id=$clientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=$redirectUrl");
}

public function callback() {
    $code = $this->input->get('code');
    $clientId = 'xxx';
    $clientSecret = 'xxxx';
    $tokenEndpoint = 'https://logincert.anaf.ro/anaf-oauthv2/v1/token';
    
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode("$clientId:$clientSecret"),
        'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
    
    $body = http_build_query(array(
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => $code,
        'redirect_uri' => base_url('etransport/callback')
    ));
    
    $this->load->library('httpclient');
    $response = $this->httpclient->post($tokenEndpoint, $body, $headers);
    $accessToken = json_decode($response)->access_token;
    
    $this->load->model('Settings_model');
    $this->Settings_model->save_access_token($accessToken);


    $data['access_token'] = $accessToken;
    $this->load->view('etransport', $data);
}
```

}`

The requirments:

– Type: OAuth 2.0
– Add Authorization Data to: Request Headers
– Grant Type: Authorization Code
– Callback URL
– URL-ul pentru autorizare: https://logincert.anaf.ro/anaf-oauth2/v1/authorize
– URL-ul pentru revocarea tokenului: https://logincert.anaf.ro/anaf-oauth2/v1/revoke
– Client ID
– Client Secret
– Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth header

I tried to use CURL but it doesnt redirect me, maybe i tried in a wrong way. I tried to make a header and put it on redirecturl, but maybe i tried wrong..

Answer (score 0):

everything was good.. The single problem was that my links are:

```
    $authorizationEndpoint = 'https://logincert.anaf.ro/anaf-oauth2/v1/authorize';
    $tokenEndpoint = 'https://logincert.anaf.ro/anaf-oauth2/v1/token';
```

instead of :

```
$authorizationEndpoint = 'https://logincert.anaf.ro/anaf-oauthv2/v1/authorize';
    $tokenEndpoint = 'https://logincert.anaf.ro/anaf-oauthv2/v1/token';
```

Thats funny....